# fluency -> fluentd using logstash encoder How to pass structured arguments to Fluentd?

Tags: logstash, fluentd

I am trying to send data to Fluentd using TCP (fluency) and using encoder **"net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"**logstash structured arguments
I am using fluency to pass log to fluentd my structured arguments getting lost only default fields getting passed.

How to pass structured arguments to Fluentd?

Output:

```
level=INFO logger=com.example.demoauditlog.audit.SampleService thread=main message=LOGIN TAG=XXX.AUDIT
```

Expected output:

```
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-03T08:43:04.141+05:30","@version":"1","message":"LOGIN","logger_name":"com.example.demoauditlog.audit.SampleService","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"User":"XXh","Item":"Audit","Event":"LOGIN","EventInfo":"Logged in successfully","Source":"1.2.3.4","payload":{"empty":true,"present":false}}
```

My logback.xml

AUDIT
        
        
        127.0.0.1
        24224

```
    <!-- [Optional] Multiple name/addresses and port numbers which Flentd placed -->

    <!-- [Optional] Additional fields(Pairs of key: value) -->
    <additionalField>
        <key>foo</key>
        <value>%username%</value>
    </additionalField>

    <!-- [Optional] Configurations to customize Fluency's behavior: https://github.com/komamitsu/fluency#usage  -->
    <ackResponseMode>true</ackResponseMode>
    <fileBackupDir>/tmp</fileBackupDir>
    <bufferChunkInitialSize>1048576</bufferChunkInitialSize>
    <bufferChunkRetentionSize>8388608</bufferChunkRetentionSize>
    <maxBufferSize>67108864</maxBufferSize>
    <flushAttemptIntervalMillis>400</flushAttemptIntervalMillis>
    <connectionTimeoutMilli>5000</connectionTimeoutMilli>
    <readTimeoutMilli>5000</readTimeoutMilli>
    <bufferChunkRetentionTimeMillis>5000</bufferChunkRetentionTimeMillis>
    <waitUntilBufferFlushed>20</waitUntilBufferFlushed>
    <waitUntilFlusherTerminated>20</waitUntilFlusherTerminated>
    <senderMaxRetryCount>5</senderMaxRetryCount>

    <!-- [Optional] Enable/Disable use of EventTime to get sub second resolution of log event date-time -->
    <useEventTime>true</useEventTime>
    <sslEnabled>false</sslEnabled>
    <!--  [Optional] If true, Map Marker is expanded instead of nesting in the marker name -->
    <flattenMapMarker>false</flattenMapMarker>


</appender>
```